# Вычислить интеграл методом трапеций

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, физика, интегральное-исчисление

У меня задача посчитать даный интеграл с точностью до 1е-2:
Величину шага h, обеспечивающего нужную точность, определить с помощью
двойного пересчета;
Нужна помощь с шагом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz

def trapezoid(a, b, n):
    h = (b - a) / (n - 1)
    x = np.linspace(a, b, n)
    f = np.cos(x) / x
    integral_trap = (h / 2) * (f[0] + 2 * sum(f[1:n - 1]) + f[n - 1])
    print(f'Integral calculated by the trapezoid method: value: %.2f' % integral_trap)


trapezoid(1, 2, 11)
```

Что мне нужно изменить?Нужна тут помощь!

Comment: Вычисляете для какого-то n, потом для удвоенного. И так, пока разница между значениями не станет меньше требуемой точности.

Answer (score 0):

Верно все запрограмировал?

```
def trapezium_method(func, min_lim, max_lim, delta):
    def integrate(func, min_lim, max_lim, n):
        integral = 0.0
        step = (max_lim - min_lim) / n
        for x in np.arange(min_lim, max_lim-step, step):
            integral += step*(func(x) + func(x + step)) / 2
        return integral

    d, n = 1, 10
    while abs(d) > delta:
        d = (integrate(func, min_lim, max_lim, n * 2) - integrate(func, min_lim, max_lim, n)) / 3
        n *= 2

    a = abs(integrate(func, min_lim, max_lim, n))
    b = abs(integrate(func, min_lim, max_lim, n)) + d
    if a > b:
        a, b = b, a
    print('Trapezium:')
    print('\t%s\t%s\t%s' % (n, a, b))

trapezium_method(lambda x: np.cos(x) / x, 1.0, 2.0, 0.01)
```

Результат:

```
Trapezium:
20  0.09    0.096
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).